# How to use Filter concept in Spring?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc

I want to know how to use the Filter concept in Spring.

I have web application in that i have lot of jsp pages which has login.jsp is the first page. So user can only go via login.jsp no one can not to access any jsp url directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters have nothing to do with Spring.  Just wire them into your web.xml if you'd like to use them.

You also have the option of implementing security - authentication and authorization - using Spring Security.  I'd recommend that you look at that if you want to use Spring to solve this problem.

Comment: Amen.  There is an entire ecosystem just within Spring Security that will address any and all issues you may want to address.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. Can u give me some sample application link to achive this please.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about Servlet Filters in Spring, but Spring does provide a couple of handy support classes for writing them. The [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) lets you use a normal Spring bean as a Filter instance, and [OncePerRequestFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) ensures that your filter runs only once per request. (Some app servers can run the filters multiple times based on forwarding and including.)